# Push notifications: how to handle the Chrome 49 to Chrome 50 upgrade?

Tags: google-chrome, web-push, progressive-web-apps

Chrome 49 does not support message bodies; Chrome 50 ([scheduled to ship on 19 April 2016](https://www.chromium.org/developers/calendar)) [does](http://blog.chromium.org/2016/03/chrome-50-beta-push-notification.html). As users upgrade from Chrome 49 to Chrome 50, how should I upgrade them from push notifications *without* message bodies to push notifications *with* message bodies?

Answer (score 1):

When users upgrade to Chrome M50, the browser will add encryption information to existing subscriptions--it's not necessary to re-subscribe to get message bodies. (That is, the [`PushSubscription`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PushSubscription) object (as returned by `getSubscription()` and `subscribe()`) will gain a `getKey()` method, and serializing the subscription via `JSON.stringify(s)` will return appropriate encryption keys.)

Therefore, aside from modifying the client and server to support and take advantage of message bodies, the main upgrade task is to tell the client that the server is interested in receiving encryption data.

There are many ways to do this, however one approach might be to add out-of-band information to the data that gets sent to the client as part of the `push` event handling process. For example the server could set a flag like `wouldLikeEncryptionData` which would tell the client to send encryption data back if (it has any).

Hence, once a user upgrades to Chrome M50, they would receive one last message without a message body; in the course of processing that message, they would send  encryption information to the server and all subsequent messages would include messages bodies.